# C# Winforms any library to draw/paint lines, shapes using mouse

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# winforms project. I want to do something similar to what Windows OS 'Paint' program does. Like selecting a shape and drag-drawing the shape on a PictureBox. Does Nuget have any library to do this? Preferably open source.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Syncfusion WinForms Diagram controls
https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/diagram

WinForms Diagram - Powerful, Feature-Rich Control

- Use an automatic layout algorithm for organizational charts and
  hierarchical trees.
- Create a flowchart, BPMN editor, floor planner
  app, and diagrams based on external data sources.
- Experience seamless
  interaction and advanced editing capabilities.

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion